# Constructor of subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, subclass, superclass

Here's the main class

```
    **
** Assignment class
**
** This class represents an Assignment. 
**
****************************************************/
public class Assignment {
private String name;
private double pointsPossible;
private double pointsEarned;

 // Assignment constructor
 //
// postcondition: all instance variables are initialized with
// the given values. 
public Assignment (String n, double ptsPoss, double ptsEarned) {
 name =n;
pointsPossible=ptsPoss;
pointsEarned=ptsEarned;
 }
// getName accessor method
 //
 // postcondition: returns the name of this Assignment public 
String getName() {
return name;
    }

// getPointsPossible accessor method
//
// postcondition: returns the points possible for this Assignment
public double getPointsPossible() {
return pointsPossible;
    }
 // getPointsEarned accessor method
//
// postcondition: returns the points earned for this Assignment
public double getPointsEarned() {
return pointsEarned;
 }
}
```

and when I attempt to use my accessors in my subclass i get an error while trying to initialize its variables

here's the subclass

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
/****************************************************
**
** CategoryAssignment class
**
** This class represents an CategoryAssignment. 
** Do not add any additional methods to this class.
**
****************************************************/
public class CategoryAssignment extends Assignment {
    // declare any new instance variables that you need here
    // don't forget to make them private!
    // don't declare more that you really need!
    // CategoryAssignment constructor
    //
    // postcondition: all instance variables are initialized with
    // the given values.     
    public CategoryAssignment (String n, double ptsPoss, double ptsEarned, String cat) {

    }

    // getCategoryName accessor method
    //
    // postcondition: returns the name of the category associated
    // with this CategoryAssignment
    public String getCategoryName() {
        return cat;
    }
}
```

I can't get the variables of the subclass to initialize. Also with this being a grade book project would it be smart to store the categories variable in an array or an ArrayList?

Comment: What error? please show stacktrace. Also, please format the code properly

Comment: I never see `cat` defined in the Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your subclass `CategoryAssignment` call the super class constructor? Something like:

```
public CategoryAssignment (String n, double ptsPoss, double ptsEarned, String cat) {
    super(n, ptsPoss, ptsEarned);
    this.cat = cat;
}
```

You will also need to define the `String cat` attribute in `CategoryAssignment`.

Regarding your second question "Also with this being a grade book project would it be smart to store the categories variable in an array or an ArrayList?", as far as I can see in the *getter*, the `cat` variable is a String. Hard to tell whether a list or an array would be most suitable with the information you provide.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as implicit constructor chaining in Java, even if the subclass' and superclass' constructors have the same signatures. You need to explicitly pass the parameters to the superclass' constructor with the `super` keyword:

```
public CategoryAssignment
    (String n, double ptsPoss, double ptsEarned, String cat) {
    super(n, ptsPoss, ptsEarned, car);
}
```

Comment: Moreover, the member `cat` isn't defined (the commented part in the second class details this)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at invoking the constructor on you base class from your sub class.

```
public CategoryAssignment (String n, double ptsPoss, double ptsEarned, String cat) {
    base(n, ptsPoss,ptsEarned, cat);
}
```

Comment: this question is in JAVA, not C#

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
You have to declare the variable *cat* in your class if you want to access to this. You must add this in your class:

```
    private String cat;
```

Next: 
the first statement in the subclass' constructor is the constructor of the superclass. In your case:

```
    public CategoryAssignment(String n, double ptsPoss, double ptsEarned, String cat) { 
       super(n, ptsPoss, ptsEarned);
       this.cat = cat; 
    }
```